# How to individually toggle vision for objects created with *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I want to know how to choose to display/hide objects in HTML created with angular *ngFor without having to manually implement a boolean variable for each one of them.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elementsArray">
    <button (click)="showElement()">{{element.name}}</button>
    <div *ngIf="showElementvar">
        Element1 data
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class example{
    elementsArray:element[] = 
        [{name:'Element 1'},
        {name:'Element 1'},
        {name:'Element 1'}]
    showElementvar = false;
    showElement(){ 
        this.showElementvar = !this.showElementvar;
    }
}
```

This will output 3 elements with their button. When I click on the button, every object will show. When I click on it again, it will hide everyone single one of them.

I could implement a variable and a method for each one, but I'm asking this question because the array will grow in the future and I can't find a solution for not having to manually keep adding boolean variables.

What I want is a button per element that hides a single div and leaves the rest unaffected.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to improve the details to get a better solution. **When I click on the button, every object will show. When I click on it again, it will hide everyone single one of them** Your implementation is same as per your requirement, Then what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elementsArray">
    <button (click)="showElement(element)">{{element.name}}</button>
    <div *ngIf="element.visible">
    Element1 data
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class example{
elementsArray:element[] = 
    [{name:'Element 1', visible: true},
    {name:'Element 1', visible: true},
    {name:'Element 1', visible: true}]

    showElement(element){ 
        element.visible = !element.visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't required changing the data structure of the elements.

- I pass element in the loop into the showElement function
- when showElement gets called, it checks to see if that element is in an set of elements called elementsShowing. If it's there, it removes that element, if not it adds it
- back in the template, I'm using ngIf with the result checking to see if that element is in the set

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elementsArray; let i = index">
  <button (click)="showElement(element)">{{element.name}}</button>
  <div *ngIf="elementsShowing.has(element)">
    Element Data
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
elementsShowing = new Set<Element>();
elementsArray: Element[]  =
  [
    {name: 'Element 1'},
    {name: 'Element 2'},
    {name: 'Element 3'}
  ]

showElement(element: Element) {
  if (this.elementsShowing.has(element)) {
    this.elementsShowing.delete(element);
  } else {
    this.elementsShowing.add(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This approach works better than the relying on an index value which can potentially change if data gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the simple solution using ANGULAR 6**

```
<div *ngFor=let item of items;let i=index">
    <div (click)="toogleItems(i)"> {{item.name}}} </div>
    <div *ngIf="ActivateIndex.includes(i)">
        someitem{{i}}
    </div>
</div>
```

MYDEMO.TS FILE

```
ActivateIndex: number[] =[];

items = SomeClass[] =[{name:'rohit'},{name:'koli'}]     


toogleItems(index){
    console.log(index);

    if(this.ActivateIndex.includes(index)){
       this.ActivateIndex=this.ActivateIndex.filter(item =>item !== index);
       console.log(this.ActivateIndex);
    }
   else{
      this.ActivateIndex.push(index);
      console.log(this.ActivateIndex);
   }
}


export SomeClass{
   name:string;
}
```